# How to set argument of an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I want to know if there is a solution to make an argument which is not organised when I create an object.

```
class Joueur:
    nbrJoueur=0
    def __init__(self,c_pseudo,c_pv=25,c_sttat=0):
        self.pseudo=c_pseudo
        self.pv=c_pv
        self.sttat=c_sttat
        Joueur.nbrJoueur+=1

j1=Joueur("adel",250,0)
j2=Joueur("salah",c_sttat=10)
```

So like in `j2` I had to make `c_sttat=10` to avoid that it's the the `c_pv` which take the value 10.
So I want to avoid that problem when I have a lot of arguments how could I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you want `args` or `kwargs`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking about. Do you want to require keywords for all arguments?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you tried to do `j2=Joueur("salah",10)` which didn't do what you want because it sets `c_pv` to 10 rather than `c_sttat` that you want. Is this right? If so, I suggest you read more about default arguments and keyword arguments to understand better how this works.

Comment: You can force the use of keyword arguments with `def __init__(self, c_pseudo, *, c_pv=25,c_sttat=0):`

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be what you want:

```
    def __init__(self,c_pseudo, *, c_pv=25,c_sttat=0):
```

When you put `*` in the parameter list, all the arguments after that position must be given with keywords. So if you try to write

```
j2 = Joueur("joseph", 10)
```

you'll get an error because you didn't name the second argument. This forces you to indicate whether it's `c_pv` or `c_sttat`